# Forge Viewer: How to Consolidate after Unconsolidate?

Tags: autodesk-forge

After loading 3D Rooms in the Forge Viewer (Revit Export to Navisworks to get the Room geometry), I'd like to change the colors of the Rooms to reflect the Revit Color Schemes, based on the Room Departments for example.

Instead of changing the Materials, setting the theming color seems to be the best option:

```
viewer.setThemingColor( fragId, color );
```

However, the material used by default for the room has 0.1 opacity and the Theming colors are confusing with the transparency, so I'd like to change the material opacity to 1.

```
var roomMat = viewer.impl.getMaterials()._materials["model:1|mat:0"];
roomMat.opacity = 1;
roomMat.needsUpdate = true;
viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
```

If I don't call 'unconsolidate', the material change has no effect.

```
viewer.model.unconsolidate();
```

The issue is that after 'unconsolidating' the model, the refresh rate is very slow on the model when orbiting, zooming, etc...

So how can I re-consolidate the model ? I haven't found what the parameters should be when calling 'consolidate'

```
viewer.model.consolidate(?, ?, ?);
```

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It can be handled by this API call, but this function is a private API and from `impl` which means it might be changed someday in the future by our engineering team. You may use it at your own risk.

```js
viewer.impl.consolidateModel(model)
```

Comment: Thanks Eason, after calling consolidateModel the model is as fast as before but the material change is lost as soon as I orbit the model. My call is as follows, I am missing something?      viewer.model.unconsolidate();
        var roomMat = viewer.impl.getMaterials()._materials["model:1|mat:0"];
        roomMat.opacity = 1;
        roomMat.needsUpdate = true;
        viewer.impl.consolidateModel(viewer.model);
        viewer.impl.invalidate(true);

Comment: If I don't call consolidateModel the Material change remains.

Comment: @Duzmac Did you managed to get the changes remained after using viewer.impl.consolidateModel(model) ?

Comment: @Thibaud no, it wasn't working for me. When I export the rooms from Revit to Navisworks, the rooms are assigned a transparent material. So at the moment I have to open the file in Navisworks, re-assign all the rooms to the Generic Material and re-save. This is a pain. Are you having the same issue?